# Сортировка элементов в Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Имеем два вложенных ресурса со связью has_many

```
#routes.rb

resources :topics do
  resources :posts
end
```

Сортирую топики по последнему посту в нем:

```
Topic.includes(:posts).order("posts.created_at desc")
```

Как сделать чтобы новый созданный топик, который не имеет постов, был первым?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сделайте проще и логичнее -- сортируйте по дате последнего обновления топика, `updated_at`. При создании он сразу задаётся равным моменту создания, а заставить его следить за постами очень просто:

```
# Post
belongs_to :topic, touch: true
```

Теперь при сохранении поста будет обновляться `updated_at` его топика, и для сортировки не потребуется лезть в ассоциацию вообще.

Если по каким-то причинам `updated_at` не может так себя вести, добавьте аналогичную колонку, а-ля `last_posted_at` и укажите её в виде символа вместо `true`, а при создании пишите туда значение `created_at` (способом на ваш выбор).

Об этой опции сказано [здесь](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#belongs-to-association-reference).

Ещё один вариант -- делать заглавный пост топика при создании темы, тогда можно сразу сортировать по `MAX(posts.created_at)`, ведь даже у новых топиков будет пост. Это потребует повозиться с вложенными атрибутами, зато не так избыточно.

Comment: Я до этого пробовал сортировать по дате обновления топика. Просто не знал про `touch: true` :) Делал через костыль. Теперь все отлично. Спасибо!

Answer (score 2):

Зависит от БД. В Postgres есть [NULLS FIRST](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-order.html), в MySQL нужно делать сортировку по вычисляемому полю (что-нибудь вроде `ORDER BY posts.created_at IS NULL DESC, posts.created_at DESC`)